# Changing navigation drawer direction

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have navigation drawer in my app that I changed it's direction to open from right to left by `layoutdirection="rtl"` but it seems to messed with everything in content of navigation drawer and every item such as view and buttons and... switched from right to left. I mean I have button somewhere right, but in simulator it appears to left.
Anyone faced this problem before? How do I fix that?

I also tried this piece of code but didn't worked out

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

Comment: do you want to flip your entire app horizontally to support countries that read and write from right to left, or just want to have the drawer open from the right because you simply prefer it that way?

Comment: Do you want the navigation menu to uneffected on RTL Switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** if you want to use

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

then add this code to manifest

```
<application android:supportsRtl="true">
```

**2)** another way to achieve this ...

`your_layout.xml:`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  tools:openDrawer="end">

 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
  android:id="@+id/nav_view"
  android:layout_gravity="end" // here you can change direction
  />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`YourActivity.java:`

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        } 
        else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_gravity="right"
```